# Returning File from byte[] not working correctly in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file

I recently posted a question asking how I can return a File from a byte[] that I am storing.

The question is here [byte[] to File Type in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617834/byte-to-file-type-in-mvc-3)

Just for reference, I have resulted to storing the binary for the file as a string.

When I return the document, I am calling the following code:

```
var data = document.BinData.ToByteArray();
return File(data, document.MIMEType,document.Extension);
```

where **BinData** is a string, and **ToByteArray()** is an extension method I wrote:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string data)
    {
        byte[] binData= new byte[data.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            binData[i] = (byte)data[i];
        }
        return binData;
    }
```

The problem I am experiencing is, when I get the file back, I am getting something like the following:

[image]

Is there anything you can see that I am doing incorrectly?

**Edit**, I have changed the following "Upload" code to the following:

```
var stream = BinData.InputStream;
                byte[] data = new byte[BinData.ContentLength];
                stream.Read(data, 0, BinData.ContentLength);

                string documentData = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

where documentData is the string I am storing:

and the download code is the following:

```
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(document.BinData);
return File(data,document.MimeType,document.Title + document.Extension);
```

where document.BinData is the documentData from above

Comment: The line "Just for reference, I have resulted to storing the binary for the file as a string" fills me with dread... in what way are you encoding that?

Comment: Your `stream.Read` line is not reliable; are you getting lots of zeros at the end? if so, I expect I can explain that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wager that the problem is in the line:

> Just for reference, I have resulted to storing the binary for the file as a string.

Based on your *decoder* (`ToByteArray`), this is not really encoded in a suitable way; note; you **cannot** treat arbitrary binary data as a string (at least, not in the way you are trying). The preferred way to do this is simply:

```
byte[] originalData = ...
string asString = Convert.ToBase64String(originalData);
byte[] reconstructedBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(asString);
```

(although several other approaches - for example hex - would work too)

This should give you back the correct `byte[]`, and all should be good from there.

---

Re your `Stream.Read` code, and assuming you already have some kind of oversized length check to prevent from DDOS, note that you should *loop* on `Read`:

```
int remaining = BinData.ContentLength, offset = 0, bytesRead;
byte[] data = new byte[remaining];
while((bytesRead = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining)) > 0) {
    offset += bytesRead;
    remaining -= bytesRead;
}
if(remaining > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
```

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum a complete (but small) input/output example would really help, to be honest...

Comment: Marc, I have added an edit above with your suggestions, but am still getting a similar, but different answer.

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum "similar, but different" you're making me guess completely. Is the file you are working with text, for example? (since you are claiming it as such in the MIME). How about a really basic "this is the file (as hex) I am uploading; this is the file (as hex) I am getting back"

Comment: it turns out your code was working, I was clicking the wrong link to download, so it turns out, I was downloading the previous files which had different encoding. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum no problem; please see the edit I made a few moments ago re your `Read`