# trying to trigger file download in MVC controller, only header gets displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I am trying to have a link re-direct to a Controller action, and then that action fetches a binary file and downloads it as an attachment.

In one of my views, I have a simple URL redirect to `Controller=Shipments`, `Action=PackingSlip` and `id=@Model.selected_pending_shipment.id`:

```
<a href="/Shipments/PackingSlip/@Model.selected_pending_shipment.id">
    <div class="row" align="center" style="padding-left:-20px;">
        <img src="/Content/Images/packing-slip.png" style="width:50px;">
    </div>
</a>
```

I receive this request in my Controller and process it here:

```
namespace Pacific.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ShipmentsController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage PackingSlip(string id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            FileInfo packing_slip_template = new FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"Content\Binaries\packingslip.xlsx");

            using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(packing_slip_template))  // Load the template in to memory
            {
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(xlPackage.GetAsByteArray());
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "packingslip.xlsx";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the majority of my actions in the Controller return an `ActionResult`, however I think I need to return an `HttpResponseMessage`.

Unfortunately, the file is never attached and my browser just redirects to a page that shows:

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers: { Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=packingslip.xlsx Content-Type: application/octet-stream }

I have also tried returning a Stream instead of ByteArrayContent to no avail.

Comment: there is method of File which is used like ``return File(fileObject)``

Comment: So then I must temporarily create the file somewhere?  I am auto-generating files, so not having temporary storage for them and keeping them in memory would be ideal.  But, I'll still look at this method.

Comment: Look at MemoryStream which is in System.IO.  Saves writing to disk first.  return File is the right approach per Ehsan's comment.

Comment: File method can accept byte array:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617834/byte-to-file-type-in-mvc-3